# Displaying 'n' number of UIView on a button click

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

In my app's add contact page, i am accepting address of the contact. i have a feature to add additional addresses when "Add additional Address" button is clicked. The concept is that the user can add any number of additional addresses. The user has to keep clicking the button to open a separate UIView which has the fields req to accept additional address. So the user has to click on the "Add Additional Address" button to keep adding the address. There has to be one UIView which has to be used again and again on clicking the button right? How to do this?

Comment: Using a table view? What have you tried?

Comment: May be instead of opening many UIView.Once user tap on Additionall address you can save the field address somewhere and cleared all those fields.No need to open multiple UIView.

Comment: @Wain: Is it possible to use a tableview for that friend? Let us consider that all the fields req for Address are placed in a custom cell.. But we should display the address view only on clicking the "Add" button right.. How to add the custom cell to the tableview on the click of the button?

Comment: @iPhoneDev: Sry friend.. Thats not possible in our application. We have different tables for contact details and additional address of the contacts. On clicking the "Save Contact" button, we first save the contact and wit the contact ID of the contact, we save the additional address in the separate table. So we need to use multiple views and once "save contact" button is clicked, all the additional addresses have to saved in the separate table at once.

Comment: @ManojEllappan no problem.seems that I am not able to get properly to your question.

Comment: @ManojEllappan are you using storyboard or xib?

Comment: @Vish: I am using xib..

Comment: @ManojEllappan then you should make a controller where you can provide required fields to make their entry. And then make IBAction of the Add button to call the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a UIView Class alloc init and add on subview and increase y offset after adding each view

Comment: Yeah i could understand. But say first i ve clicked "add additional address" button and i have typed in the values. Now when i click the "Add Additional address" button again, i have to alloc the UIView and the views inside it right.. But where to store the previously typed in values..

Comment: you can store all views  in NSMutableArray and you can make your textfield as property so you can access value.

Or you can simply store all address as string value in NSMutableArray

Comment: same scenario... any sample link

Answer (score 0):

this is how i created dynamic textfeilds same way u can generate uiview

```
-(void)dynamicTextfeildsPhone
{
    string = Points.text;
    Pointsvalue = [string intValue];
    txtFldFrame1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45,130,60,30)];
    for (x=1; x <= Pointsvalue ; x++)
    {
        txtFldFrame1=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45,txtFldFrame1.frame.origin.y+34,60,30)];
        txtFldFrame1.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        txtFldFrame1.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
        txtFldFrame1.tag = 1;
        txtFldFrame1.delegate=self;
        [ScrollLag addSubview:txtFldFrame1];

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ssn in the above code points is the number of uiviews u want to generate supply frame to ur uiview then loop it to generate more by increasing y distance of each uiview

Comment: why we didn't use custom tableview here?... i think that is very simple right